# Swap two statement on adjacent lines in C when one statement takes multiple lines

Tags: c

Assume that I have the following code:

```
int x;
string s = "some very long "
           " string";
```

I would like to have one command that swaps the order of these without ending up with something like:

```
string s = "some very long"
int x;
           "string";
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Does `C-M-t` (`transpose-sexps`) help? It's supposed to, but maybe it doesn't in C.

Comment: Nope, it does something very different.

Comment: It might depend on where you put the cursor. Dunno what Emacs considers a sexp in C. Perhaps it is not very sophisticated. You might see whether any of the other `transpose-*` commands (`transpose-paragraph`?) help at all here. Anyway, probably there are 3rd-party libraries that offer what you request, and hopefully someone will let you know here.

Comment: I would suggest: 1) highlite one of the statements 2) 'yank' the statement 3) 'put' the statement in its' new location.  When you have developed a macro that will yank from start of statement (??beginning of line??) to first semicolon, then add feature to search for next semicolon then step forward past newline, then paste.   Then you can use that macro for what you want to perform.  (probably a LOT faster to just perform the steps via keyboard and mouse actions)  Be sure to save that macro into the emacs startup file

Comment: Maybe `sp-transpose-hybrid-sexp` [docs](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Hybrid-S-expressions) from `smartparens` will do it, at least it you put parenthesis around the pair of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `smartparens`. For non-lisp languages it has the useful notion of ["hybrid s-expression"](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Hybrid-S-expressions). Its command `sp-transpose-hybrid-sexp` doesn't quite work directly on your example, but if you are willing to wrap those two string in parenthesis it does work (also, Emacs seems to indent much better with the added parenthesis). If you run it on the following text with the point any where in `string s =` it will correctly swap the two declarations:

```
int x;
string s = ("some very long "
            " string");
```

Answer (score 0):

[anchored-transpose](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/anchored-transpose.el) may be another option.

Bind `anchored-transpose` to `C-x t`, then you can mark the first statement, press `C-x t`, mark the second statement, press `C-x t`, and these two statements are swapped. It seems **NOT** very convenient at the first sight, so it's better if you use it with other packages which can quickly mark the statements.

EDIT: I've just realized that `anchored-transpose` may not be a good solution to this special case. If you quickly mark the region, you can just do a `C-w` to kill the region then paste it. `anchored-transpose` should fit some more general cases where there are no something like `sexp` or `statement`, just random texts.